# Replace a constrained STRTOSET parameter in MDX with an actual value

Tags: date, parameters, mdx

I don't know MDX and I'm trying to get this MDX query from a very old SSRS report to run in Management Studio so I can see what the output of the On columns values are. I have no idea how to replace the parameter of @DateFrom in the query below with a value so I can make it run.

The SSRS report inputs a standard dd/mm/yyyy date with a default using the expression:

```
=DateAdd("D",-1,Today())
```

I need to run this for specific dates in January of this year:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[LeftLcuno] AS 'LEFT([Customers].[Lcuno].CurrentMember.Name,8)' 
MEMBER [Measures].[RecordTypeFileHeader] AS '"2"'
MEMBER [Measures].[RecordID] AS '"XX33"'
MEMBER [Measures].[RecordTypeOutletHeader] AS '"07"'
MEMBER [Measures].[RecordTypeDepHeader] AS '"09"'
MEMBER [Measures].[DepartmentCode] AS '"3"'
MEMBER [Measures].[RecordTypeCreditDetail] AS '"12"'
MEMBER [Measures].[CreditAmount] AS [Measures].[Sum Of Things]

SELECT {[Measures].[Sum of Things]} 
On Columns,
NON EMPTY 
{
[Customers].[Customer Ref Code].[Customer Ref Code] AS OutletCode*
[Customers].[Customer Branch Name].[Customer Branch Name] AS OutletName*
[Bag Details].[Voucher Slip Date].[Voucher Slip Date]*
[Bag Details].[Processing Date].[Processing Date]*
STRTOSET(@DateFrom,CONSTRAINED)
}
On Rows
From TheCube
WHERE 
(
{FILTER([Customers].[Lcuno].[Lcuno],[Measures].[LeftLcuno]="20009000")},
[Bag Details].[Bag State].&[Done and Archived]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your cube it is hard to say.

Likely it is a date from your Calendar or Date dimension.

So likely you can replace with something like this:

```
[Date].[Date].&[20050109]
```